# R extract specific text inside a string

Tags: r, regex, string, stringr

I have a data.table with 1 Million rows with each cell looking like this:

> ENST00000408384 // ENSEMBL // ncrna:miRNA chromosome:GRCh37:1:30366:30503:1 gene:ENSG00000221311 gene_biotype:miRNA transcript_biotype:miRNA // chr1 // 100 // 100 // 0 // --- // 0 /// ENST00000469289 // ENSEMBL // havana:known chromosome:GRCh38:1:30267:31109:1 gene:ENSG00000243485 gene_biotype:lincRNA transcript_biotype:lincRNA // chr1 // 100 // 100 // 0 // --- // 0 /// ENST00000473358 // ENSEMBL // havana:known chromosome:GRCh38:1:29554:31097:1 gene:ENSG00000243485 gene_biotype:lincRNA transcript_biotype:lincRNA // chr1 // 100 // 100 // 0 // --- // 0 /// OTTHUMT00000002840 // Havana transcript // novel transcript[gene_biotype:lincRNA transcript_biotype:lincRNA] // chr1 // 100 // 100 // 0 // --- // 0 /// OTTHUMT00000002841 // Havana transcript // novel transcript[gene_biotype:lincRNA transcript_biotype:lincRNA] // chr1 // 100 // 100 // 0 // --- // 0

I need to extract what comes immediately after "gene_biotype:" (in this case it would "miRNA"). How to do that?

I tried finding a solution with stringR and regex and gave up after several hours. Appreciate your help.
Thanks.

Comment: There is **gene_biotype:lincRNA** as well. Don't you want to take that also?

Comment: sure, this is also necessary. Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 1):

You could try `regmatches` with `regexpr`.

```
regmatches(x, regexpr("(?<=gene_biotype\\:)\\w*", x, perl=TRUE))
# [1] "miRNA"
```

---

*Data:*

```
x <- "
ENST00000408384 // ENSEMBL // ncrna:miRNA chromosome:GRCh37:1:30366:30503:1 gene:ENSG00000221311 gene_biotype:miRNA transcript_biotype:miRNA // chr1 // 100 // 100 // 0 // --- // 0 /// ENST00000469289 // ENSEMBL // havana:known chromosome:GRCh38:1:30267:31109:1 gene:ENSG00000243485 gene_biotype:lincRNA transcript_biotype:lincRNA // chr1 // 100 // 100 // 0 // --- // 0 /// ENST00000473358 // ENSEMBL // havana:known chromosome:GRCh38:1:29554:31097:1 gene:ENSG00000243485 gene_biotype:lincRNA transcript_biotype:lincRNA // chr1 // 100 // 100 // 0 // --- // 0 /// OTTHUMT00000002840 // Havana transcript // novel transcript[gene_biotype:lincRNA transcript_biotype:lincRNA] // chr1 // 100 // 100 // 0 // --- // 0 /// OTTHUMT00000002841 // Havana transcript // novel transcript[gene_biotype:lincRNA transcript_biotype:lincRNA] // chr1 // 100 // 100 // 0 // --- // 0
"
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use regex lookaround with `str_extract`

```
library(stringr)
str_extract(df1$col1, "(?<=gene_biotype:)\\w+")
#[1] "miRNA"
```

If we need all the elements, use `str_extract_all`

```
str_extract_all(df1$col1, "(?<=gene_biotype:)\\w+")
#[[1]]
#[1] "miRNA"   "lincRNA" "lincRNA" "lincRNA" "lincRNA"
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(col1 = "\nENST00000408384 // ENSEMBL // ncrna:miRNA chromosome:GRCh37:1:30366:30503:1 gene:ENSG00000221311 gene_biotype:miRNA transcript_biotype:miRNA // chr1 // 100 // 100 // 0 // --- // 0 /// ENST00000469289 // ENSEMBL // havana:known chromosome:GRCh38:1:30267:31109:1 gene:ENSG00000243485 gene_biotype:lincRNA transcript_biotype:lincRNA // chr1 // 100 // 100 // 0 // --- // 0 /// ENST00000473358 // ENSEMBL // havana:known chromosome:GRCh38:1:29554:31097:1 gene:ENSG00000243485 gene_biotype:lincRNA transcript_biotype:lincRNA // chr1 // 100 // 100 // 0 // --- // 0 /// OTTHUMT00000002840 // Havana transcript // novel transcript[gene_biotype:lincRNA transcript_biotype:lincRNA] // chr1 // 100 // 100 // 0 // --- // 0 /// OTTHUMT00000002841 // Havana transcript // novel transcript[gene_biotype:lincRNA transcript_biotype:lincRNA] // chr1 // 100 // 100 // 0 // --- // 0\n"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-1L))
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not the best but it works fine.

```
splited <- strsplit(text," ")[[1]]
splited <-gsub("*.gene_biotype:","",splited )
unique(gsub("gene_biotype:","",splited[grepl("gene_biotype:",splited)]))
```

gives,

```
"miRNA"   "lincRNA"
```

**Data:**

```
text <- "ENST00000408384 // ENSEMBL // ncrna:miRNA chromosome:GRCh37:1:30366:30503:1 gene:ENSG00000221311 gene_biotype:miRNA transcript_biotype:miRNA // chr1 // 100 // 100 // 0 // --- // 0 /// ENST00000469289 // ENSEMBL // havana:known chromosome:GRCh38:1:30267:31109:1 gene:ENSG00000243485 gene_biotype:lincRNA transcript_biotype:lincRNA // chr1 // 100 // 100 // 0 // --- // 0 /// ENST00000473358 // ENSEMBL // havana:known chromosome:GRCh38:1:29554:31097:1 gene:ENSG00000243485 gene_biotype:lincRNA transcript_biotype:lincRNA // chr1 // 100 // 100 // 0 // --- // 0 /// OTTHUMT00000002840 // Havana transcript // novel transcript[gene_biotype:lincRNA transcript_biotype:lincRNA] // chr1 // 100 // 100 // 0 // --- // 0 /// OTTHUMT00000002841 // Havana transcript // novel transcript[gene_biotype:lincRNA transcript_biotype:lincRNA] // chr1 // 100 // 100 // 0 // --- // 0"
```